# Ubuntu 18.04 two finger scroll

Tags: 18.04, touchpad

I have a Dell Inspiron 14 5000 series laptop where I have installed Ubuntu 18.04. However, the two finger scrolling is not working.

Also, I have seen from some posts that there should be separate settings for mouse and touch pad. But as per the image, I only have settings for mouse and no touchpad.

Any solutions/suggestions to this would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What is Ubuntu 18? Ubuntu uses 18.04 and 18.10.  If Ubuntu 18 refers to MINT that is off topic. Install Ubuntu 21.04 and you likely will see a touchpad opti

Comment: I will edit your question to harmonize the - so far - given information. If you recognize any inconsistencies or false information, please edit the question by yourself.

Comment: Its ubuntu 18.04